# Google Ad Words API reports ошибка ReportDownloadError.MISSING_PARAMETER

Tags: google-adwords

Пробую делать как в документации, отправляю такой запрос:

```
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201802



 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201802">
     <selector>
        <fields>CampaignId</fields>
        <fields>Clicks</fields>
        <fields>Cost</fields>
     </selector>
      <reportName>Custom Adgroup Performance Report</reportName>
      <reportType>ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
      <dateRangeType>LAST_7_DAYS</dateRangeType>
      <downloadFormat>XML</downloadFormat>
    </reportDefinition>
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reportDownloadError>
    <ApiError>
        <type>ReportDownloadError.MISSING_PARAMETER</type>
        <trigger>Missing report definition</trigger>
        <fieldPath></fieldPath>
    </ApiError>
</reportDownloadError>
```